# Vue.js: bind value of text-field by cycling through array values

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm using Firebase Firestore and Vue.js, and I want to display data from documents in textfields.
E.g. below: my documents in my collection Papers have fields alpha, beta, gamma.

Is there a way to bind the value as items in the array docItems? I have tried all I can think of, using '' marks, "this.docItems[n]" which didn't work, etc... I can't get it to cycle through and display one of each docItem. Any suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

```
<v-card class="mx-auto pa-3 ma-2 text-center" v-for="Paper in Papers" :key="Paper.id">
  <v-row class="d-flex justify-space-around pa-0 ma-0">
    <v-col cols="1" class="d-flex pa-0 ma-0" v-for="n in 3" :key="n">
      <v-text-field outlined autocomplete="false" :value="Paper.alpha"></v-text-field>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //Showing various combinations I tried:
      docItems: ['Paper.alpha', Paper.beta, 'gamma'],

...

firestore: {
    Papers: db.collection("Papers")
  },

...

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you:

```
<v-card class="mx-auto pa-3 ma-2 text-center" v-for="Paper in Papers" :key="Paper.id">
  <v-row class="d-flex justify-space-around pa-0 ma-0">
    <v-col cols="1" class="d-flex pa-0 ma-0" v-for="i in docItems" :key="i">
      <v-text-field outlined autocomplete="false" :value="Paper[i]"></v-text-field>
```

and

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      //Showing various combinations I tried:
      docItems: ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'],

...

firestore: {
    Papers: db.collection("Papers")
  },

...

</script>
```